# Getting values from database sql

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to get the values of certain fields in the database.
I tried :

```
 pr.command.CommandText = string.Format("select amount from storage where code =12");
            SqlDataReader read = pr.command.ExecuteReader();
            int currAmount = int.Parse(read["amount"].ToString());
```

but it didnt work and the error was : illegal try to call when there is no data.
but there is a record with the field code =12

Anyone can help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the first record at the beginning and check if there even is one

```
if(read.Read())  {
   int currAmount = int.Parse(read["amount"].ToString());
   ....
}
```

Comment: There is a record. i can see it in the database

Comment: You should always check that and put the `read.Read()` in an `if` (or `while` if you have more than 1 record).

Comment: You could also use the HasRows property/method (can't remember if it is a property or a method) before you even attempt the `while(read.Read())` loop. I say to use the `while` because there may be multiple records and you want to continue to `read()` but only `while` there are rows there.

Comment: @juergend whoops, I should have read your comment before posting mine. Nevertheless, I'll leave mine there just to be sure ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In your current situation there is data from the database but the reader hasn't read it yet. You have to call [`Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read.aspx) first to read a row from the database:

```
pr.command.CommandText = string.Format("select amount from storage where code =12");

SqlDataReader read = pr.command.ExecuteReader();

while (read.Read())
{
    int currAmount = int.Parse(read["amount"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: No problem. Since you are new, don't forget to mark the question as answered by checking the checkmark before the answer that was most helpful. (Please also review your other questions)